# How to connect to Amazon MySQL db with Xamarin Forms?

Tags: mysql, database, forms, amazon-web-services, xamarin

I'm developing a cross-platforms app using Xamarin Forms and i need to use a database, so I choose Amazon MySQL database because I need a relational database. My question is, how can I connect to this database using Xamarin Forms? Because I search it but I found only solutions for SimpleDB and others that aren't relational.

Answer (score 0):

I think through WebServices.

Here a good document
[connecting-remote-database-xamarin-forms](https://xamarinhelp.com/connecting-remote-database-xamarin-forms/)

After WS creation, you can use HttpClient

Something like

```
var uri = "https://api.domain.com/v1/products/1";


HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
var response = await client.GetAsync(uri);
```

this is a good documentation about [http performance](http://jonathanpeppers.com/Blog/improving-http-performance-in-xamarin-applications)

Comment: So I should use the API. But should Amazon have standard api?

Comment: I've already read it, but I think these API don't allow me to execute query on the database.